# Importing Javascript files without instantiating the functions and bundle to Js

Tags: javascript, webpack, import

I am trying to create sort of a javascript library to use on different projects inside one directory

This is sort of the structure

```
- JSlib
  - function1.js
  - function2.js
  - function3.js
- projects
  - project1
    - public
      - bundle.js
    - src
      - main.js (imports function1, function2) 
    webpack.config
  - project2
    - public
      - bundle.js
    - src
      - main.js (imports function3) 
    - webpack.config
```

The main.js would ideally look like this

```
import { func1 } from function1.js
import { func2 } from function2.js
import { func3 } from function3.js
...
```

basically sort of a config file specifying which js files are needed for that specific project.

I am trying to use webpack to bundle the javascript into a bundle.js but i cannot seem to get it working.
I can only import but i cannot use the function right away if that make sense.

some functions are meant to be defined and not instantiated
for example of a function:

```
export function toggleSlideover() {
    document
        .getElementById("slideover-container")
        .classList.toggle("invisible");
    document.getElementById("slideover-bg").classList.toggle("opacity-0");
    document.getElementById("slideover-bg").classList.toggle("opacity-25");
    document.getElementById("slideover").classList.toggle("-translate-y-full");
}
```

this function is only defined and used by the components, but webpack wont bundle it if i dont "use" it. I cannot seem to just import and define it.

I tried redundant definition

```
import { toggleSlideover as tsl } from "../../../../jslib/mobileNav.js";

function toggleSlideover() {
    tsl();
}
```

but it complains that the function is not being used.

Simple imports are not working

and

```
import { toggleSlideover } from "../../../../jslib/mobileNav.js";

toggleSlideover();
```

would initiate the function right away (which is not what i want)